# My regex is not working properly

Tags: python, regex

My regex is not working properly. I'm showing you `before regex text` and `after regex text`. I'm using this regex `re.search(r'(?ms).*?{{(Infobox film.*?)}}', text)`. You will see my regex not displaying the result after `| country        = Assam, {{IND` . My regex stuck at this point. Will you please help me ? thanks

Before regex:

```
    
{{Infobox film
| name           = Papori
| released       = 1986
| runtime        = 144 minutes
| country        = Assam, {{IND}}
| language       = [[Assamese language|Assamese]]
| budget         = 
| followed by    = free
}}
```

After regex:

```
    
{Infobox film
| name           = Papori
| released       = 1986
| runtime        = 144 minutes
| country        = Assam, {{IND
```

Why regex stuck at this point? `country        = Assam, {{IND`

Edit : Expecting Result

```
Infobox film
    | name           = Papori
    | released       = 1986
    | runtime        = 144 minutes
    | country        = Assam, {{IND}}
    | language       = [[Assamese language|Assamese]]
    | budget         = 
    | followed by    = free
```

Comment: What is the result you are expecting and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is catching everything between the first `{{` and the first `}}`, which is in the "country" entry of the infobox. If you want everything between the first `{{` and the *last* `}}`, then you want to make the `.*` inside the braces greedy by removing the `?`:

```
re.search(r'(?ms).*?{{(Infobox film.*)}}', text)
```

Note that this will find the *last* `}}` in the input (eg. if there's another template far below the end of the infobox, it will find the end of that), so this may not be what you want. When you have nesting things like this, regex is not always the best way to search.

Comment: this is probably a dumb question, but what does (?ms) mean?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know in that context. Usually it means that the previous element (letter or group) is there either 0 or 1 time (i.e. is optional). After a `*` it means that the `*` is non-greedy, and if it was `(?:ms)` it would mean that this group should not be captured. But without the `:` I'm not sure what it means, or if it's just a typo.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow thanks for info. So is it better to use  `film.*?`. Is it possible to replace this text `| country        = Assam, {{IND}}` to `| country        = Assam, IND`?

Comment: @aleph_null: prob = 1.0 ... it's the inline equivalent of the flags `re.M + re.S` aka `re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL`; see docs

Comment: @GraemePerrow: go to http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax then do a Ctrf-F search for `sux`

Comment: Did you mean, "make the `.*` inside the braces **greedy** by removing the `?`" (emphasis mine)?